# Arduino Leonardo problem uploading from Rasbian Arduino IDE

Tags: pi-4, arduino

I recently installed Arduino IDE on my Raspberry Pi 4 and I'm trying to program an Arduino Leonardo through it. I wander if anyone experienced anything like this I'm getting here, as I searched a lot the web and nothing came out after hours.

Arduino IDE is at the latest version, board is correctly set to Arduino Leonardo, and the port too.

I getting error:

```
avrdude: Expected signature for ATmega32U4 is 1E 95 87

   Double check chip, or use -F to override this check.

Wrong microcontroller found.  Did you select the right board from the Tools > Board menu?
```

Comment: "the latest version" - which is?

Comment: @Milliways 1.8.12

Comment: You should ask on https://arduino.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you have software installed which tries to talk to the Arduino at the same time as the IDE. For instance, [`modemmanager`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/7690#issuecomment-490264042) is known to cause trouble.

Run `udevadm test $(udevadm info --query=path --name=/dev/ttyUSB0)` (or whatever the name of your Arduino is) and check the output for any udev rules that are executed. You may see rules which define the device name, but if there's any communication software started automatically on a new serial port, it may be the root cause.